# How to correlate Image DN with Spectrometer reflectance?

Tags: convert, image

I am trying to develop a system to measure NDVI from the commercial grade digital camera.

I am trying to get two bands NIR and RED from the image and apply it for NDVI measurement using diffent filters. I also want to apply the Spectrometer reading on field to validate the NDVI measured from the Images.

Can anyone help me, how to correlate spectrometer reading(Normally Reflectance of the surface) and the image DN(Three Layer Image) ??

Comment: Are you trying to apply a raster image to a point cloud? What sort of data is the spectrometer returning?

Comment: Spectrometer returning data will be the reflectance of the object under investigation in different wavelength ranging from 350 to 1100nm. So i need to correlate this data with the image DN taken using Normal digital camera. My first task would be to change image DN to reflectance. So is there any methods to change normal digital camera image DN to reflectance value ?Any suggesstions, recommendation please???? Thanks.

Comment: Is the spectrometer data in the form of a point cloud? A raster? Just numbers in a spreadsheet? A regular image? There are quite a few tools that will let you apply data to an image, but I'm not sure how your spectrometer data is stored on a computer. Also, this question seems highly specific.